# jQuery / JavaScript - Appending a select ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code to generate a dropdown menu, and a dropdown which says 2/4/8, based on whatever the user selects, that number of dropdowns will be created.

Here is the template code:

```
div.row.hidden#rowTemplate
    label.control-label(for="team") Team:
    div.controls
        select#team1(style='width: 160px;')
            include teamsDropDown
```

And here is the JS to generate the dropdowns:

script(type='text/javascript')

```
$("#nTeamSelector").change(function(){
    var nTeams = $("#nTeamSelector").val(); // Get the value of the team selector that you use
    $("#rowContainer").empty() // Delete all existing dropdowns
    for (var i=0; i<nTeams; i++){
        var newRow = $("#rowTemplate").clone(); // Exact copy of the element generated by Jade
        /*
        * here you should change all the little fields that 
        * make the dropdowns different. For example:
        */
        //newRow.children(".control-label").setText("Team "+(i+1)+":");
        newRow.attr('id', 'team'+(i+1)+'Row');
        newRow.removeClass("hidden");
        $("#rowContainer").append(newRow);
    }
});
```

At the moment I cannot get the `setText` line to work as I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setText'`. As well as this, every dropdown generated has a `select` with an `id` of `#team1` which is brought over from the rowTemplate code, and I would like to append this to be team`i` for each drop down generated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after [`.text( textString )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

```
newRow.children(".control-label").text("Team "+(i+1)+":");
```

---

To change the `select`'s `id` you will need to select it as well and apply the `id`. Something like this:

```
newRow.find('select').attr('id', 'team' + (i + 1));
```